# Why is my swift code running out of order?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code and it appears to execute out of order.

```
var theauth = 0
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        let usersRef = ref?.child("Users")
        let queryRef = usersRef?.queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: emailTextField.text!)
        queryRef?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for snap in snapshot.children {
                let userSnap = snap as! DataSnapshot
                let thechild = userSnap.key
                print(thechild + "Hi")
                if thechild != ""{
                    theauth = 3
                    print(thechild + "1")
                }else if self.password2.text == self.passwordTextField.text{
                    theauth = 1
                }else{
                    theauth = 2}
            }
        })

        print(theauth)
```

Output prints in reverse order than what I'd expect:

```
0 //theauth value
-Lf9xUh53VeL4OLlwqQoHi //thechild value + Hi
-Lf9xUh53VeL4OLlwqQo1  //thechild value + 1
```

Thoughts???

Comment: Hint: asynchronous

Comment: Please read this essay, which I wrote just for you: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Comment: i don't have an async statement in my code.

Comment: https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-the-firebase-apis-asynchronous-e037a6654a93

Comment: Methods that take a completion closure are asynchronous.

Comment: "i don't have an async statement in my code" Yes, you do.

Comment: “Methods that take a completion closure are asynchronous.” ... Not entirely true. More accurately, they _frequently_ are asynchronous, but not always. But in this case, `observeSingleEvent` absolutely is an asynchronous method, though.

Comment: @Rob I'm curious. Under what situation would a method have a completion closure that isn't asynchronous? Anything that is synchronous doesn't need a completion closure. There are obviously plenty of cases of synchronous methods that take other closures, but not completion closures. At least none I can think at the moment.

Comment: You keep using the term “completion closure”. But the OP doesn’t use that term, nor does method signature. (And it’s arguably not the appropriate term for observer pattern, anyway.) I just wanted to make sure that no one walked away with the incorrect conclusion of “oh, there’s a closure, so (a) it must be “completion closure” and (b) the method absolutely must be asynchronous” because, as you say, that’s not always the case. That’s all I’m saying. I would left it at slightly weaker claims like “methods with closures are frequently asynchronous” or “observers are generally asynchronous”.

Comment: @Rob I specifically used the term "completion closure" to avoid confusion with other closure arguments. Certainly not all (not even most) closures are completion closures. But those that are, mean the method is async, at least by my use of the term "completion closure". My mistake for not clarifying what I specifically meant by "completion closure".

Comment: No worries. I knew exactly what you meant and I know you know your stuff, so I apologize for making such a big deal about it. I just know that I’ve answered questions/comments in the past stemming from from noobs who learned about asynchronous patterns and then getting subsequently confused when they later stumble across synchronous methods with closures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is async and takes longer to run than the print statement at the end. Consider adding your print statement when you set the variable, or calling a method to execute that print statement when the query has finished.

```
var theauth = 0
ref = Database.database().reference()
let usersRef = ref ? .child("Users")
let queryRef = usersRef ? .queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: emailTextField.text!)
queryRef ? .observeSingleEvent( of: .value, with: {
  (snapshot) in
  for snap in snapshot.children {
    let userSnap = snap as!DataSnapshot
    let thechild = userSnap.key
    print(thechild + "Hi")
    if thechild != "" {
      theauth = 3
      print(thechild + "1")
    } else if self.password2.text == self.passwordTextField.text {
      theauth = 1
    } else {
      theauth = 2
    }
  }
  print(theauth)
})
```

Comment: placing the print inside the last parenthesis works.  Seems silly but I didn't realize that those functions would run asynchronously.

Comment: Great! Feel free to mark the answer as correct if you feel it could help other users in the future.